# Redirect a specific page on one website to a specific page on another website

Tags: .htaccess-configuration, redirect

I am hoping someone may be able to help me. I am not experienced enough with .htaccess and rewrite etc to understand what is needed.

I have the following already switched on in my Joomla global config.

- Search Engine Friendly URLs Yes
- Use URL Rewriting Yes
- Add Suffix to URL YEs

Basically, I just want page link `xyz.org/patents` to redirect to `zzz.org/patents`

I have tried in cpanel but this doesn't seem to work because Joomla overides my cpanel redirect.

I can get `xyz.org` to redirect `zzz.org` but cannot do individual links which is what I require.

Comment: Can you show use what specific things you tried in cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file try this...

```
Redirect 301 "/patents" "http://www.zzz.org/patents"
```

Just add it at the bottom of the file. Sorry if formatting is weird, I'm on my cell.

Answer (score 0):

Or try using the Joomla Redirect component, providing the xyz.org site is the one running Joomla. Set the expired url to /patents and the "new url" to https://zzz.org/patents.

There are third-party extensions that get in the way of this component doing its job, so it may not always work, but it's worth a try if you're having trouble making other ways work.